# Is there any analogue of malloc_history for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I need to debug a usage after free problem in a rather big piece of software. It would be great if I could see stack traces of the code that allocated it and the code that freed it.

Comment: Have you tried gcc's/clang's `-fsanitize=address`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen, on Windows, I can't use clang, I'm stuck with MSVC++.

Comment: Use the debug version of malloc and free using `crtdbg.h`. More details can be found in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.80).aspx) and other related articles

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant, could you post it as an answer? It kinda does the job.

Comment: It is just link soup.  Please post your answer, describe how the tool solved your problem.